# Finding number of numbers between $1$ and $10,000$ whose sum of digits is $19$

Tags: combinatorics, permutations, generating-functions

I am asked to find the number of numbers between 1 and 10,000 whose sum of digits is 19. (I am aware that there's a similar question previously on here, but hear me out please, I have a different doubt).

When I assumed the number to be a 4 digit number with leading zeroes possible, I came up with the required situation as $$x_1+x_2+x_3+x_4 = 19$$

where $9\geq x_1,x_2,x_3,x_4\geq 0$

and the answer to the is the coefficient of $x^{19}$ in $(1+x+x^2+...+x^9)^4$ which is 660 which is the correct answer.

**BUT** I cant understand the mistake in the way I approached the question 1st, which was taking two cases.

*1st Observation*: Clearly, no 1 digit or 2 digit number satisfies, as the max value for 2 digit number is 9+9 = 18 (for 99)
So, clearly, there remain two cases, a 3 digit and a 4 digit number.

Taking a 3 digit number, **abc**, $a  \geq 1, b,c \geq 0$ (if a = 0 then wont be 3 digit)

Here, again, $a+b+c = 19$, and then, if i take $a-1 = k \geq 0$, then it turns out to be $$k+b+c=18$$ where $k,b,c \geq 0$. The required number of numbers of 3 digit would be:

The coefficient of $x^{18}$ in $(1+x+x^2+....+x^9)^3$

And, similarly taking the case for 4 digit numbers, the answer for that would be the coefficient of $x^{18}$ in $(1+x+x^2+....+x^9)^4$

And the total answer would be the sum of these two cases, but that came out to be greater than 660. What did I do wrong? Am I adding extra cases here? If so, how?

Comment: The generating function is $$\frac{\left(1-x^{10}\right)^4}{(1-x)^4}$$ and you want to find the coefficient of $x^{19}.$ Note that you can handle all digits as once and treat the numbers as four digits from $0$ to $9.$ Leading zeroes don’t change the number.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews Yes, I came up with the correct answer using that method...by considering a 4 digit and having leading zeroes. But can't it be done by taking the two cases as I stated?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since $a$ can only be from $1$ to $9$, and you subtract $1$ from $a$ so it starts at zero, $a-1$ ends at $8$, rather than $9$.
The contribution of $a-1$ would be $1+x+x^2+\ldots+x^8$, not $x^9$

Comment: Could you please elaborate why?

Comment: Yes, you are right. Thank you so much. I am pretty new to these kind of questions and online learning in India is tough as teachers don't have a good internet connection and conveying doubts online is a problem. Thank you